# Get the image in file - lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, attachment, files

I have to display an image in a lightning component. So in Salesforce classic I put this image in an attachment related to an object,  but in lightning experience there is no attachment, or I didn't find them. There is only the possibility to add a file.

My question is how can I retrieve this file in my component ? For an attachment I retrieve the attachment like that :

```
List<Attachment> img = [select Id, Name, ContentType, parentId from Attachment 
                            where parentId in :listeId and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif')];
```

and in my component I put that :

```
<img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.image.Id}" alt=""/>
```

but it doens't retrieve me the url of the image in the file.

Comment: As of Spring 17 release, notes and attachments are replaced by Lightning notes and files. You will need to query chatter files, instead of attachment.

Comment: And how can I get the url of the image in the file after that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the base64 encoded string from the Attachment, you can use that as src of the image.

Example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Embedding_an_image_via_data_URL

Also check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511375/6110447

**Edit:**
Query for Body of the Attachment, it is base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this example](https://github.com/metacursion/home/blob/master/docs/lightning-not-hotdog/hotdogCmp/hotdogCmpController.js#L10). It reads a local file and displays content as image.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.
Use the below code

```
     doInitHelper : function(component, event) {var attachmentList = component.get("v.attachmentList");
        console.log('attachmentList--->',attachmentList);
        var slides = [];
        for(var i in attachmentList){
            slides.push("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+attachmentList[i].Id);
        }
        component.set("v.slides",slides);
       component.set("v.currentSlide",slides[0]);
    }
```

component code

```
  <img src="{! v.currentSlide}" height="500" width="500"/>
```